# Python -Nested Dictionary - values to pass to a formula and calculate the result

Tags: python, function, class, dictionary, nested

I have been trying to solve this problem, but am going around in circle. I have two questions regarding the following nested dictionary coding problem.

**1) Kilojoules calculation** - I wanted to calculate the kilojoules of each diet based on the values from the diets_data nested dictionary. However, when I manually check the answer, I find out that the formula I have written does not give me the correct answer.

```
def diet_choose_diet():
    diets_data = {
            'Normal': {'protein': 32.50, 'carbohydrates': 60.00, 'fat': 40.86},
            'Oncology': {'protein': 35.00, 'carbohydrates': 52.50, 'fat': 37.63},
            'Cardiology': {'protein': 32.50, 'carbohydrates': 30.00, 'fat': 26.88},
            'Diabetes': {'protein': 20.00, 'carbohydrates': 27.50, 'fat': 27.95},
            'Kidney': {'protein': 15.00, 'carbohydrates': 55.00, 'fat': 23.65}}

    # ****************** Normal Diet *****************************
    for diet_name, info in diets_data.items():
        if diet_name == 'Normal':
            print(diet_name)
            for value in info.values():
                print("%.2f" % value)
                # kilojoules = 4.18 * (4 * protein + 4 * carbohydrates + 9.30 * fat)
                kilojoules = 4.18 * (4 * 32.50 + 4 * 60.00 + 9.30 * 40.86) # correct answer = 3134.99
            print("%.2f" % kilojoules)
            # Incorrect Formula
            for pro_carb_fat in info:
                normal_kilojoules = 4.18 * (4 * info[pro_carb_fat]) + (4 * info[pro_carb_fat]) + (9.30 * info[pro_carb_fat])
            print("%.2f" % normal_kilojoules)

    # ****************** Oncology Diet *****************************
    for diet_name, info in diets_data.items():
        if diet_name == 'Oncology':
            print(diet_name)
            for value in info.values():
                print("%.2f" % value)
                # kilojoules = 4.18 * (4 * protein + 4 * carbohydrates + 9.30 * fat)
                kilojoules = 4.18 * (4 * 35 + 4 * 52.50 + 9.30 * 37.63) # correct answer =
            print("%.2f" % kilojoules)
            # Incorrect Formula
            for pro_carb_fat in info:
                oncology_kilojoules = 4.18 * (4 * info[pro_carb_fat]) + (4 * info[pro_carb_fat]) + (9.30 * info[pro_carb_fat]) # this formula gives me the incorrect answer.
            print("%.2f" % oncology_kilojoules)

print(diet_choose_diet())
```

**2) Code refactoring** - In the above code, I am duplicating code for each diet. I have attempted to put it in the class to clean up. However, I am not getting the output I want (I have started learning about classes a few weeks back and am still learning the concepts). I have gone through questions posted here. May be I have missed the posts that clarify the questions I want to clarify. If you could share the link, that would be greatly appreciated. I will study more. Thanks in advance!

```
class DietDisplay:

    def __init__(self, diet, protein, carbohydrates, fat):
        self.diet = diet
        self.protein = protein
        self.carbohydrates = carbohydrates
        self.fat = fat
        self.kilojoules = 0

    def getDiet(self):
        diets_data = {
            'Normal': {'protein': 32.50, 'carbohydrates': 60.00, 'fat': 40.86},
            'Oncology': {'protein': 35.00, 'carbohydrates': 52.50, 'fat': 37.63},
            'Cardiology': {'protein': 32.50, 'carbohydrates': 30.00, 'fat': 26.88},
            'Diabetes': {'protein': 20.00, 'carbohydrates': 27.50, 'fat': 27.95},
            'Kidney': {'protein': 15.00, 'carbohydrates': 55.00, 'fat': 23.65}
        }

        for diet_name, info in diets_data.items():
            print(diet_name)
            for diet in info:
                print(info[pro_carb_fat])
                self.kilojoules = 4.18 * (4 * (diet_name[diet]['protein']) + 4 * (diet_name[diet]['carbohydrates']) + 9.30 * (diet_name[diet]['fat']))

        return self.kilojoules

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = DietDisplay()
    print(d.getDiet('Normal', 34, 45, 36))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solution:

Do the following thing in main method. You are passing 4 parameters to ** **init**** function. So while creating obj of **class** you need to pass those parameters and then call the function. You can see in the code that you are passing parameters to **init** function (i.e. the class) and not to **getDiet** function.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = DietDisplay('Normal', 34, 45, 36)
    d.getDiet()
```

OR

Simply while creating obj of **class** you need to pass those parameters and then call the `getDiet` function in the **init** method of class:

**Check that I have made changes in main method and __init__ function of class and for loop in getDiet function**

```
class DietDisplay:

    def __init__(self, diet, protein, carbohydrates, fat):
        self.diet = diet
        self.protein = protein
        self.carbohydrates = carbohydrates
        self.fat = fat
        self.kilojoules = 0
        self.getDiet()

    def getDiet(self):
        diets_data = {
            'Normal': {'protein': 32.50, 'carbohydrates': 60.00, 'fat': 40.86},
            'Oncology': {'protein': 35.00, 'carbohydrates': 52.50, 'fat': 37.63},
            'Cardiology': {'protein': 32.50, 'carbohydrates': 30.00, 'fat': 26.88},
            'Diabetes': {'protein': 20.00, 'carbohydrates': 27.50, 'fat': 27.95},
            'Kidney': {'protein': 15.00, 'carbohydrates': 55.00, 'fat': 23.65}
        }

        for diet_name, info in diets_data.items():
            print(diet_name)
            self.kilojoules = 4.18 * (4 * (diets_data[diet_name]['protein']) + 4 * (diets_data[diet_name]['carbohydrates']) + 9.30 * (diets_data[diet_name]['fat']))

            print(diet_name +":"+ str(self.kilojoules))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = DietDisplay('Normal', 34, 45, 36)
```

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav! In the professional environment, which method is preferred? `self.getDiet()` in the `__init__` def function or without? Another question I have is `d = DietDisplay('Normal', 34, 45, 36)` . The value I entered are just dummy values. It doesn't get printed. If I don't put in anything, I cannot call the function. For professional code writing, what kind of test values should I pass so that it still let the class the function knows that some values have been included. Sorry to bug you again! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
normal_kilojoules = 4.18 * (4 * info[pro_carb_fat]) + (4 * info[pro_carb_fat]) + (9.30 * info[pro_carb_fat])
```

`pro_carb_fat` will be the same value for each part of the calculation. It will be run once for each `pro_carb_fat` in info. The printed value will be the last one calculated. You'll just get `4 * fat + 4 * fat + 9.3 * fat`

You could instead take the sum and use a lookup to find the multiple. The you can just use:

```
multiples = {
    'protein': 4,
    'carbohydrates': 4,
    'fat': 9.3
}

for diet_name, info in diets_data.items():
    normal_kilojoules = 4.18 * sum(
        multiples[pro_carb_fat] * info[pro_carb_fat] 
        for pro_carb_fat in info
    )
    print(diet_name, ": %.2f" % normal_kilojoules)
```

Prints:

```
Normal : 3134.99
Oncology : 2925.83
Cardiology : 2089.93
Diabetes : 1880.73
Kidney : 2089.77
```

If those multiples change for different diets, it would be a good use for a class that has these multiples as a property.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Appreciate your help. Could I ask you about this code? `for diet_name, info in diets_data.items():
    normal_kilojoules = 4.18 * sum(
        multiples[pro_carb_fat] * info[pro_carb_fat] 
        for pro_carb_fat in info
    )` . In this code, `multiples[pro_carb_fat]` look up each value and multiply with corresponding protein, carb, fat. Is this writing method called dictionary comprehension? ` for pro_carb_fat in info` part makes sure multiple matches with corresponding value? Thanks! I will update my question code after I get reply from you for future reference for others.